# Why cross validation result shows high accuracy while there is overfitting?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using random tree algo for binary classification problem. Training set contains 70k values as "0" class and  only 3k as "1". In addition, result of predicting on `X_test`  should give same amount of  "0" and "1".

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1, n_estimators=350, min_samples_split=6, min_samples_leaf=2)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, x_train, y_train, cv=cv) 
print("Accuracy (random forest): {}+/-{}".format(scores.mean(), scores.std()))
```

> Accuracy (random forest): 0.960755941369/1.40500919606e-06

```
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction_final = clf.predict(X_test) # this return Target values: 76k Zeroes and only 15 ones 


#x_test is 10% of x_train set
preds_test = clf.predict(x_test)
print "precision_score", precision_score(y_test, preds_final)
print "recall_score", recall_score(y_test, preds_final)
```

> precision_score 0.0;
> recall_score 0.0
>
> confusion_matrix [[7279    1]
> [ 322    0]]

As far I can see, there is the overfitting problem, but why doesn't cross validation detect it? Even standard deviation is very low. So how can I fix that problem?

P.S. I've tried to take 3k rows with "0" and 3k with "1" - as training set, model is much better, but this is not solution.

Comment: `precision_score 0.0; recall_score 0.0` this should definitely ring your alarm bells. Have you checked if the train and test set are reasonable?

Comment: @cel Actually these sets has been taken from kaggle competition, this is why they are reasonable. The point is  I dont know to deal with them

Comment: Have you looked at the confusion matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Overall) Accuracy* is a nearly useless measure for unbalanced data sets like yours, since it computes the percentage of correct predictions. In your case, imagine a classifier that would learn nothing, but just always predict "0". Since you have 70k zeroes and only 3k ones, that classifier would reach an accuracy score of `70/73 = 95.9%`.

Inspecting the [*Confusion Matrix*](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#confusion-matrix) is often helpful for disclosing such a "classifier".

Thus, you should definitely use another measure to quantify classification quality. *Average Accuracy* would be an option, since it computes the average accuracy over all classes. In the case of binary classification, it is also called [*Balanced Accuracy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#In_binary_classification) and results in computing `(TP/P + TN/N)/2`, so that the classifier imagined above, which always predicts "0", would only score `(100% + 0%) / 2 = 50%`. However, that measure seems to be not implemented in `scikit-learn`. Though you could implement such a scoring function by yourself, it will probably be easier and faster to use one of the other [predefined scorers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter).

For example, you could compute the [F1 Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) instead of Accuracy by passing `scoring = 'f1'` to `cross_validation.cross_val_score`. The F1 Score takes both precision and recall into account.

Comment: Now I see, I knew  about precision_score and recall, but forget about F1 Score, which seems to be the solution)